# Modeling a URDF file

Tags: ros, urdf, blender, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to model a URDF file, using blender or other similar software?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9477/modeling-a-urdf-file./) by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2011-03-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi GeniusGeeko,

you may export your model done in Blender into collada and then use collada_urdf converter to convert into URDF format: https://kforge.ros.org/robotmodel/robot_model/file/d33189ce4a62/collada_urdf/src/collada_urdf.cpp
D.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-03-18**:
Alright, awesome! Thanks for this. I'm testing it now.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe that any 3d modeling software can directly output a URDF file.

I believe that the best way to go about creating a URDF file from a CAD package is to export a set of your critical dimensions as a CSV file or the like.  Most, if not all, CAD packages allow you to define a set of critical dimensions to export.  You can then parse these critical dimensions into a set of XACRO variables that you can use in the rest of your URDF files.

Once you have set this up once, you could then just re-export the CSV and re-run your parser each time that the 3d model changes.

You can also export your STL files to allow for "prettier" robot models.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-03-18**:
Alright thanks, I'll check it out. If I don't like it, I'll stick to making them from scratch.